# ImportError: No module named BIO

Tags: macos, importerror, biopython

I'm very new in programming, and so in Python. Subsequently, I have a problem I don't know how to solve.

I'm working on a Mac OS with a script designed to work with BioPython. I think that after a lot of work I finally had got BioPython installed correctly, after trying lots of times to install NumPY, but when I try to run my script I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named Bio
```

My script begins like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Bio import SeqIO
secuencias=SeqIO.parse("/Users/imac/Documents/Gradiente
glaciares/Secuencias/Rocas/Rocas_Pia/Roca_Pia0.fna", "fasta")
```

I've also tried to insert first:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "//Users//imac//Desktop//BioPython")
```

to make the script read from other directory, but then I have:

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Finally I tried to import the Bio module from the Python path and there I have no problems to do it, so I think the module will be installed correctly.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try to re-install Bio on Mac OS X:

Download [this](http://bcc.bx.psu.edu/courses/_downloads/Bio.zip). Than unpack it and move the folder named Bio to:

```
Macintosh HD/Frameworks/Python Framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Than try running the script again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I got through the problem by simply copying the script to the BioPython folder and running it from there. Now I have a problem with the script's parameters themselves :(

Comment: sorry to hear.. if you're stuck post another question. If you'll put the source in the right libs you could run the code from anywhere. If you already have the `BioPython` module try and put it under `Macintosh HD/Frameworks/Python Framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This will fail:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "//Users//imac//Desktop//BioPython")
```

with:

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

unless you first did:

```
import sys
```

Python is trying to tell you that the name 'sys' is not defined, and since in this case it is a library the reason for this is you didn't tell Python to import it.